# Error: cannot import name 'notebookapp' from 'notebook'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Python in VS Code with Jupyter notebook.
I'm a new student about Python.
I installed the VS Code and Python3, and also Python, Jupyter notebook and so on in VS Code in Mac OS.
When I typed 'print(123)', the ERROR was occurred, and the details are below.

Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.12.1 64-bit (/usr/local/bin/python3)'.
ImportError: cannot import name 'notebookapp' from 'notebook' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/notebook/**init**.py)
View Jupyter log for further details.

log >>
Visual Studio Code (1.64.0, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2022.1.1301854968.
Python Extension Version: 2022.4.1.
Error 20:10:08: Exception while attempting zmq : [Error: No native build was found for platform=darwin arch=arm64 runtime=electron abi=89 uv=1 armv=8 libc=glibc node=14.16.0 electron=13.5.2

==

I typed 'pip3 install jupyter'
and 'python3 -m ipykernel install --user'.
The exact same error is occurred though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have a Jupyter kernel on VS Code:

1. On VS Code menu go to **View** > **Command Palette...**
2. Type 'kernel' and select **Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel**

If you don't have one, install the 'Jupyter' plugin.

If you do, check that the path to Python is the same as that given by the command `which python3` in your terminal. Otherwise, modify your VS Code path to match them.

Hoping to solve your problem.